# Please help me clear my confusions about WordPress

Tags: themes, templates

I am building a website in WooCommerce.

What is most efficient way to replace the original theme site template pictures? Do we replace them with same size and pixel pictures and nothing wrong will happen to allignment? For example if main page header picture of a product is 1920 * 1000 then we crop pic to this size and replace it with ELEMENTOR? And then keep going on with all the pictures in the template to make it yours

Thank you

Comment: Please keep to a one question per question policy, this isn't a discussion forum thread and you need to be able to mark an answer as the correct answer, you can't do that if you bundle up your questions. It also means it's impossible to write an answer unless you can answer all 3 questions at once. Also questions specific to 3rd party themes are offtopic

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.